# Create a relationship that allows a user to follow multiple types of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on a system that allows a user to follow different records (funds or wallets) but I am blocking on relationships.

I have three models: `User`, `Fund` and `Wallet`.
A user must be able to follow to multiple funds or wallets, and a fund or wallet must be able to have multiple followers.

The goal is to be able to do `user.follows` which would give me the list of records he follows (funds and wallets), and to do `fund.followers` or `wallet.followers` and get the list of users who follow these records.

I have created this table:

```rb
class CreateFollows < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :follows do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :followable_id
      t.string :followable_type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

then I did:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :follows, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```rb
class Follow < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :follower, foreign_key: :user_id, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :follows
  belongs_to :followable, polymorphic: true
end
```

and this concern that I added to `Fund` and `Wallet` models:

```rb
module Followable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :followers, dependent: :destroy
  end
end
```

I know it can't work as it is now, but I don't really understand what to put in the User model and in my concern. Can someone show me the path please?

Comment: Have you read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did the following:

```rb
class Follow < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :follower, foreign_key: :user_id, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :follows
  belongs_to :followable, polymorphic: true
end
```

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :follows, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :funds_followings, through: :follows, source: :followable, source_type: 'Fund'
  has_many :wallets_followings, through: :follows, source: :followable, source_type: 'Wallet'

  def followings
    funds_followings + wallets_followings
  end
end
```

```rb
module Followable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :follows, foreign_key: :followable_id, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :followable
    has_many :followers, through: :follows, as: :followable
  end
end
```

So I'm able to do everything I wanted.